# Generating a cyclic subgroup from an element

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups, cyclic-groups

Let's say G is the symmetric group of degree 5. Suppose I wanted to find the cyclic subgroup generated by the permutation $x = (1,2,3)(4,5)$.

I know that the order of x is 6 - so I know the cyclic subgroup will have 6 elements.

To find the cyclic subgroup, would it be sufficient to simply find $x^0, x^1, x^2, x^3, x^4, x^5, x^6$ - is this set guaranteed to be the cyclic subgroup generated by x? And is this always the case?

Thanks for any help,

Jack

Comment: Yes, provided you already know the order of $x$. But note, you don't need $x^6$ since you already have it as $x^0 = 1$.

Comment: Thanks - is it obvious or is there a sort of proof?

Comment: Yes, it's sort of obvious. Clearly, the elements 
$$1,x,x^2,x^3,x^4,x^5$$
are elements of the cyclic subgroup generated by $x$.
But they must be distinct, else if $x^i = x^j$ with $0 \le i < j \le 5$, then $x^{j-i}=1$, contrary to the fact that $x$ has order $6$.

Answer (score 1):

The cyclic subgroup generated by an element $x$ is by definition the set of powers
$$\{x^k|k\in\mathbb Z\}$$
If $x$ is of finite order $n$, this is just
$$\{x^0,\ldots,x^{n-1}\}=\{x^1,\ldots,x^n\}$$
You can actually prove this. Give it a shot.